# Python Functions Swapping of numbers

Tags: python, function

If we write a simple program in python as mentioned below, the variables get swapped

```
num1=5
num2=10
temp = num1
num1 = num2
num2 = temp
```

print(num1)   //10

print(num2)   //5

But if we perform the same thing inside a function, the values do not get swapped

```
def swap(x, y):
   
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
```

Driver code

```
x = 2
y = 3
swap(x, y)
print(x)    //2
print(y)    //3
```

I want to know the concept that in first case it is getting swapped but in second case why it is not getting swapped ?

Comment: You've introduced local variables in the function that just happened to be named the same... If you had `def swap(a, b)`, what would you have expected? And when you set an equality, you're reassigning a reference, not "storing a value" to that variable name

Answer (score 0):

You can swap x and y like this

```
x,y=y,x
```

If you want to wrap it in a function

```
def swap(x,y):
    return y,x

x,y = swap(x,y)
```

Comment: That i know it can be swapped like this. I want to know the concept that in first case it is getting swapped but in second case why it is not getting swapped ?

Comment: Because your function is not returning anything.

Comment: Returning doesn't matter. OP is expecting the passed in references to change